# Switch() and foreach() issues in php

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

I'm trying to put a `foreach()` inside of a switch. But I got the following error code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting
>   case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in
>   /.../index.php on line 20

I'm getting the `$lang` value from à `$_GET['']`

```
$dir = 'content/'.$lang;
    $scan = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..','.'));
    switch($page) {
        foreach ($scan as $value){
        $value_ext_free = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            case $value_ext_free :
                $page = $value_ext_free;
                break;
        }

        default :
            $page = 'welcome';
    }
```

It seems pretty logical to me, but I'm not a PHP specialist... Any idea?

**EDIT**

I just update my code with this:

```
$dir = 'content/'.$lang;
    $scan = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..','.'));
    foreach ($scan as $value){
        $value_ext_free = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    }
    if($page == $value_ext_free) {
        include  'content/'.$lang.'/'.$page.'.php';
    }   
    else { 
        include  'content/'.$lang.'/welcome.php';
    }
```

It is almost working except that only the last page of my folders is working in the content... :/

Thankssss! :)
Katsele

Comment: You need to specify a case for the foreach part of switch. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: `switch($page) { case "something":
        foreach ($scan as $value){`

Comment: `case $value_ext_free :` should be outside foreach (along with `break;`)

Comment: Actually I want each item of my `foreach()` to be a case of the switch... Is it even possible ?

Comment: Do you know what are all the values which will come from `foreach()` ?

Comment: Not like the way you are trying to do. You will have to write switch/case for each item in the foreach or use individual if/else conditions.

Comment: Yes I do, all the filenames of my folder.

Comment: I wanted to save some lines by generatting all the cases automatically. It it another way to do so?

Comment: I think you need to get rid of switch/case entirely and then use foreach() and then do the condition checking as you iterate through foreach.

Comment: Since you don't know what are all the values will come in `foreach`, try to use `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correction to your updated code:

```
$dir = 'content/'.$lang;
$scan = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..','.'));
$default = true;
foreach ($scan as $value){
    $value_ext_free = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if ($page == $value_ext_free) {
        include  'content/'.$lang.'/'.$page.'.php';
        $default = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ($default) {
    include  'content/'.$lang.'/welcome.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` has to be directly next to the switch

Foreach will do an iteration for each index of the array
If i understand correctly what you want (your code does not seems pretty logical for me sorry) you may be need something in that way

```
$dir = 'content/'.$lang;
$scan = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..','.'));

    foreach ($scan as $value){
        $value_ext_free = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $page = $value_ext_free;

    }
    if(!isset($page))
        $page = 'welcome';
```

Comment: I'm using a `$_GET` to include the content of my pages. To avoid getting bad URL, I want to list all the cases. I came up with a `foreach()` and a `switch()` to solve it... But it doesn't work. I'm not sure if it is clear...

Comment: Ok then then solution of @sjagr seems to be what you need

Answer (score 0):

> This method of implementation is dangerous and not recommended.

[PHP Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) I am pretty sure that you need to have a case token, something like:

`Case X` and have the statement block inside it. And hence the for each block inside it.

Seems like you don't even need switch for this.

```
$dir = 'content/'.$lang;
if(file_exists($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $GET['filename']))
    $page = $GET['filename'];
else
    $page = 'welcome';
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems it doesn't take in consideration the fact that `$page` is changing whenever my `$_GET['']` is... :)

Comment: @katsele Ah, I think I got what your are trying to achieve here. Replace $GET['filename'] with the variable that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

for switch statements use the following syntax

```
<?php
switch ($variable) {
    case 'value':
        runFunction1('value');
        break;

    case 'value2':
        runFunction1('value2');
        break;

    default:
        runFunction1('default');
        break;
}
?>
```